# wordpress dashboard display custom error message upon custom condition

Tags: wordpress

In edit-user.php of wordpress dashboard before updating meta information I am checking one condition and upon failure of that condition I want to display a error message. I tried to echo div with updated class and also tried WP admin_notices hook but no luck

```
 add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
 add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );  

function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
global $wpdb;        

    if(CONDITION TRUE) {
    update_usermeta( ........... );
    }
    else {
     WANT TO DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hook for validating user extra fields. This hook will call before updating user details.

You can display error message like this:-

```
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'validate_extra' );
function validate_extra(&$errors, $update = null, &$user  = null)
{
    if (!$_POST['YOUR_FIELD'])
    {
        $errors->add('YOUR_FIELD', "<strong>ERROR</strong>: YOUR ERROR MESSAGE.");
    }
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_profile_fields' );
function save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id )
{
    global $wpdb;

    update_usermeta( ........... );
}
```

Comment: you saved my day I have been trying to find the hook for this...Please advise how we can get these kind of hooks information

Comment: You can find any WordPress `Action Hooks` [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) And `Filter Hooks` [Here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference)